# Can't insert values into Heroku Database

Tags: mysql, heroku

I have some troubles with working with clearDB addon in Heroku App. At first I've received some datas to work with my database. By 'heroku config' typed in cmd I got the URL and I splitted it into necessary datas such: hostname, database, password etc. 
I have two .php files. First one is posting datas from inputs to second .php file where I'm connecting with database.

I got connected properly and I created the table called `Bot` in my database exactly with two columns called `pytanie` and `odpowiedz`. But the problem is with inserting datas into the created table. In the output lines it looks like the rows are being added in table but I can't see the values that should be placed in the rows.

What's more I put the same code on my localhost database and everything worked fine. So I think the problem is regarding to the configuration of heroku.

```php
        $username = 'b4***2a81c221';
        $password = '6e9***5f';
        $database = 'heroku_**2a1241ce5c716';
        $hostname = 'us-**br-iron-east-02.cleardb.net';

        $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

        if($conn->connect_error) die("Błąd!");


    $pytanie = $_POST['pytanie'];
    $odpowiedz = $_POST['odpowiedz'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `bot` (pytanie, odpowiedz) VALUES('dasd','asd')";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . $conn->error;
        exit;
    }

    $select = "SELECT * FROM bot";
    $result = $conn->query($select);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ($select) from DB: " . $conn->error;
        exit;
    }
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Pytanie: " . $row["pytanie"]. " - Odpowiedz " . $row["odpowiedz"];
    }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }

$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. It's silly but the problem was connected with case sensitivity. My rows were 'Pytanie' and 'Odpowiedz' not 'pytanie' and 'odpowiedz. Greetings ;)